# How to change the labels to the image (icon) in bar chart.js

Tags: image, chart.js, label

Help me, please.
How to change the labels to the image (icon) in bar chart.js ?
I mean, change from this 
[change labels: "LifeWall_files/logo.png","Bodily Functions","Sleep"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs8c0.png)

to this 
[bottom icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDzPw.jpg)

Comment: have you added images onto chart ?

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way to do this would be to get a font that includes these icons and then set the font family for the ticks

```
  ...
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          fontFamily: 'FontAwesome'
        }
      }]
    }
  }
};
```

and then specify the appropriate character codes in your labels

```
labels: ["\uf24e", "\uf1b9", "\uf242", "\uf0fc", "\uf236"],
```

---

With the FontAwesome CSS, the above would give you

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I need different images.

Comment: Smart move. Font generators out of icons might also be used with this same idea.

Comment: Is there any way to add custom images instead of font awesome smilies?
as font-awesome icons are of having std color height width etc, so i need to replace it by custom .png or .jpg files, is it possible ?

Answer (score 9):

The [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api) offers a range of hooks that may be used for performing custom code. You can use the `afterDraw` hook to draw images (icons) instead of tick labels directly on the canvas using [`CanvasRenderingContext2D`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D).

> You'll also have to instruct Chart.js not to display the default tick labels. This can be done through the following definition inside the chart options.

```
scales: {
  xAxes: [{
    ticks: {
      display: false
    }
  }],
```

> Further you need to define some padding at the bottom of the chart, otherwise you'll see only part of the images.

```
layout: {
  padding: {
    bottom: 30
  }
},
```

Please have a look at the runnable code snippet below.

```js
const labels = ['red vans', 'blue vans', 'green vans', 'gray vans'];
const images = ['https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RAv2.png', 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tq5DA.png', 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KRtW.png', 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLyVi.png'];
const values = [48, 56, 33, 44];

new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), {
  type: "bar",
  plugins: [{
    afterDraw: chart => {      
      var ctx = chart.chart.ctx; 
      var xAxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
      var yAxis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'];
      xAxis.ticks.forEach((value, index) => {  
        var x = xAxis.getPixelForTick(index);      
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = images[index],
        ctx.drawImage(image, x - 12, yAxis.bottom + 10);
      });      
    }
  }],
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My Dataset',
      data: values,
      backgroundColor: ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'lightgray']
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    layout: {
      padding: {
        bottom: 30
      }
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    },    
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{ 
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          display: false
        }   
      }],
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="90"></canvas>
```

Comment: it's possible to do this with sprites?

Comment: We're using ChartJS ~v3.8.0 in our project so the config was slightly different but one thing was missing from this code snippet for us and it was to wait for the image to load before drawing the image onto the canvas. Solution came from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/15058168/1037894