# Chart.js Custom Image for Each Point

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm using Chart.js and I'm looking for help with custom images for each point on a scatter graph. I've tried using a javascript array of images but it isn't working. I'm new to canvas and html5.

What I would like is for each point to be a small profile picture of the user instead of a circle.

An example would be greatly appreciated.

I currently have:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("member-graph-scatter");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Miles / Feet',
                data: [<?php echo $member_scatter_graph_miles_climbing; ?>],
                backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.6)",
                borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Feet Climbed (ft)'
                    }
                }],
                xAxes: [{
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Miles Ridden (miles)'
                    },
                    type: 'linear',
                    position: 'bottom'
                }]
            },
            showLines: false
        }
    });
```

This graph works fine, however, the points are obviously default circles.

According to documentation I need to use:

"If the option is an image, that image is drawn on the canvas using drawImage. Image, Array" viewable at: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/

Answer (score 13):

```
var yourImage = new Image(),
    yourImage.src ='http://your.site.com/your_image.png';
data = {
      labels: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Label1',
        pointRadius: [0,0,0,0,20],
        pointHoverRadius: [0,0,0,0,20],
        pointHitRadius: [0,0,0,0,20],
        pointStyle: ['', '', '', '', yourImage],
        data: [1,2,3]
      }, {
        label: 'label2',
        pointRadius: [0,0,0,0,20],
        pointHoverRadius: [0,0,0,0,20],
        pointHitRadius: [0,0,0,0,20],
        pointStyle: ['', '', '', '', yourImage],
        data: [1,2,3]
      }]
```

Comment: Please elaborate your code. Code should always come with some kind of explanation. Thanks! :)

Comment: is it possible to add images as labels ??

Comment: Finally I find how to set an image for a single point, didn't know you could put arrays there too

Comment: @PardeepJain did you find how to add image in label ?

Comment: @PardeepJain No luck. It's BAD Luck :( No problem. Thank you for update.

Comment: @PardeepJain  see this link for labels as images: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36979474/how-to-change-the-labels-to-the-image-icon-in-bar-chart-js
for radar chart, add a new data set with points as images

Answer (score 9):

Here is a more complete example. It shows how you can set styles for individual points or for all points.

```
  var yourImage = new Image()
  yourImage.src ='http://your.site.com/your_image.png';
  var imageData = {
    labels: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Label1',
      pointRadius: [10, 0, 10, 10],
      pointHoverRadius: 20,
      pointHitRadius: 20,
      pointStyle: ['rect', yourImage, 'triangle', 'circle'],
      pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(0,191,255)",
      data: [1.5, 2.3, 3, 2.5]
    }]
  }
  window.onload = function() {
    var lineID = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
    var lineChart = new Chart(lineID, {
      type: 'line',
      data: imageData,
      options: {}
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to accomplish this in a Vue app (built with Webpack), and landed on the following solution. Import an image and create an image element like so:

```
import myIcon from '@/assets/my-icon.svg'

const chartPoint = new Image()
chartPoint.src = myIcon
```

Then in your chart.js dataset options (adjust to your needs):

```
{
  data: data,
  pointRadius: 10,
  borderWidth: 0,
  pointStyle: chartPoint,
...
}
```

[drawImage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) takes various types of image elements, but the easiest is just an HTMLImageElement, which you can create in your markup or with Javascript, as above.