# Adding Image inside Linechart points in ChartJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-visualization, chart.js, linechart

I'm developing a project using ChartJs. I am trying to add icon image inside the `line chart` instead of `points`.

I'm attaching an image in which I demonstrate the above requirements. In that image, there is a ChartJs image and a reference image. I would like to add an image inside the line chart of ChartJs exactly like in the reference image(sun and cloud icon).

[image: Chart examples]

Is it possible in ChartJs?

Comment: I found the responses to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38624222/chart-js-custom-image-for-each-point/60674490#60674490 more helpful.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As said in the [Chart.js line chart data structure](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-data-structure) (*pointStyle attribute*) :

> **pointStyle**
>   *String, Array< String >, Image, Array< Image >*
>   The style of point. Options are 'circle', 'triangle', 'rect', 'rectRot', 'cross', 'crossRot', 'star', 'line', and 'dash'. **If the option is an image, that image is drawn on the canvas using *drawImage***.

So you just need to edit your chart and put an image instead of the default `circle` in the `pointStyle` attribute of a specific data.

---

You can do it using [Chart.js plugins](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-creating-plugins) like this :

```js
// Variables 'sun' and 'cloud' are created before with `new Image()`

Chart.pluginService.register({
    afterUpdate: function(chart) {
        chart.config.data.datasets[0]._meta[0].data[7]._model.pointStyle = sun;
        chart.config.data.datasets[1]._meta[0].data[2]._model.pointStyle = cloud;
    }
});
```

And will give you [this result](https://jsfiddle.net/0cjxp0as/).

Comment: Is there a way to set the opacity of this image? I tried adding style="opacity: 0.5;", but it seems to just take the raw image.

Comment: I've got this somewhat working. The image only displays successful on hover or click. I'm using react-chart-js. any suggestion?  how can i get access to afterupdate?

Comment: [Seems to be similar](https://github.com/jerairrest/react-chartjs-2#chartjs-object) as the original library