# How to set an icon as a custom point on chart load with React Chartjs?

Tags: charts, react-chartjs

Looking for guidance/example on how to use an icon/image in place of the data point in a line chart? I’m using react-chartjs and importing Line wrapper component. Not entirely sure how to implement drawImage from [Chartjs docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/elements#point-styles). I’m somewhat new to both so I may be overlooking something obvious. Your help is greatly appreciated.

[Best example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38918324/adding-image-inside-linechart-points-in-chartjs) I can find for the effect.

This is the chart I have so far: [react-chartjs line mood tracker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyaQf.png)