# ChartJs line chart - display permanent icon above some data points with text on hover

Tags: chart.js

I have a chart i need to draw that, in addition to the data points, i want an icon permanently above (some) data points with a custom text string.

I don't need the default value popover as i can make do with a custom legend, but i need to add an icon above one or two points, and on hover of the icon, display a popover. i need to build the popover text string from non-chart related data.

The custom data labels don't appear to be flexible enough to allow different icons/popovers on different data points, i may be wrong though.

Another possibility is [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/), but I'm not sure about that.

[image: line graph with custom icon]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case your chart (canvas) is of fixed size, you can easily solve this problem by adding an additional `dataset` that specifies nothing but the icons to be shown in the chart.

```
{
  data: data2.map((v, i) => imageIndexes.includes(i) ? v + 1.2 : null),
  fill: false,
  pointStyle: icon,
  pointRadius: 22,
  pointHoverRadius: 22
}
```

Given the data array `data2` and the array `imageIndexes`, the `data` of the icons `dataset` can be built using [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Note that the values - where any - are derived from corresponding values in `data2` but slightly increased to make the images appear on top of them.

```
data2.map((v, i) => imageIndexes.includes(i) ? v + 1.2 : null)
```

Further you'll need to define a [`tooltips`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-configuration) object inside the chart `options` in order to style the popup and to make sure, tooltips are only displayed when the mouse hovers over the icons.

```
tooltips: {
  filter: tooltipItem => tooltipItem.datasetIndex == 2,
  titleFontSize: 16,
  titleAlign: 'center',
  callbacks: {
    title: (tooltipItem) => tooltipItem.length == 0 ? null : tooltipText,
    label: () => null
  }
},
```

Please have a look at the runnable code snipped below.

```js
const labels = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
const alerts = ['B', 'D'];
const data1 = [0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1];
const data2 = [1, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2];
const imageIndexes = [1, 3];
const tooltipText = 'Efficiency of Standard Curve\nnot opimal';

var icon = new Image();
icon.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvlWY.png';

const chart = new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
        data: data1,
        fill: false,
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
        borderColor: 'blue',
        lineTension: 0,
        pointRadius: 5,
        pointHoverRadius: 5,
        pointBorderWidth: 3,
        pointHoverBorderWidth: 3,
        pointBorderColor: 'white',
        pointHoverBorderColor: 'white'
      },
      {
        data: data2,
        fill: false,
        showLine: false,
        backgroundColor: 'orange',
        pointRadius: 4,
        pointHoverRadius: 4
      },
      {
        data: data2.map((v, i) => imageIndexes.includes(i) ? v + 1.2 : null),
        fill: false,
        pointStyle: icon,
        pointRadius: 22,
        pointHoverRadius: 22
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: false,
    title: {
      display: false
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    tooltips: {
      filter: tooltipItem => tooltipItem.datasetIndex == 2,
      titleFontSize: 16,
      titleAlign: 'center',
      callbacks: {
        title: (tooltipItem) => tooltipItem.length == 0 ? null : tooltipText,
        label: () => null
      }
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: 0,
          max: 6,
          stepSize: 1
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" style="width: 500px; height: 200px"></canvas>
```

Comment: May I ask is there a way to display the icon differently for each data points? For example at imageIndexes 1: the icon A, at imageIndexes 3: icon B.

Comment: @truongnm: This answer may serve as a starting point to let you find a solution for your case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62102825/2358409

Comment: Thanks for your hint!! I found another answer that set the pointStyle in array?! https://stackoverflow.com/a/41806015/3280050. Although, from the docs, pointStyle doesn't support Array  https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/elements.html#point-styles. Let me try both and get back here, thanks for your tip anyway

Comment: I got it works with the afterDraw approach. Thanks a lot! I have another question, I got error in the part pointStyle: icon, it said ReferenceError: Image is not defined. I'm using server side rendering, seems like browser specific object Image() is not available. May I ask how can I fix this? Thank you!!