# How to change line chart data label to icon or image in chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, linechart

I want to change data label text to icon or image.

[image: This chart show labels with months. I want to change this label text to icon or image]

This chart show labels with months. I want to change this label text to icon or image

Answer (score 1):

The [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api) offers a range of hooks that may be used for performing custom code. You can use the `afterDraw` hook to draw images instead of tick labels directly on the canvas using [`CanvasRenderingContext2D`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D).

> You'll also have to instruct Chart.js not to display the default tick labels. This can be done through the following definition inside the chart options.

```
scales: {
  xAxes: [{
    ticks: {
      display: false
    }
  }],
```

> Further you need to define some padding at the bottom and right of the chart, otherwise you'll see only part of the images.

```
layout: {
  padding: {
    bottom: 30,
    right: 15
  }
},
```

Please have a look at the runnable code snippet below.

```js
const labels = ['2020-02-06', '2020-02-07', '2020-02-08', '2020-02-09'];
const images = ['https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RAv2.png', 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tq5DA.png', 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KRtW.png', 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLyVi.png'];
const values = [48, 56, 33, 44];

new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), {
  type: "line",
  plugins: [{
    afterDraw: chart => {      
      var ctx = chart.chart.ctx; 
      var xAxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
      var yAxis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'];
      xAxis.ticks.forEach((value, index) => {  
        var x = xAxis.getPixelForTick(index);      
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = images[index],
        ctx.drawImage(image, x - 12, yAxis.bottom + 10);
      });      
    }
  }],
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My Dataset',
      data: values,
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: 'green',
      borderColor: 'green'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    layout: {
      padding: {
        bottom: 30,
        right: 15
      }
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{ 
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          stepSize: 20
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'day',
          tooltipFormat: 'MMM DD'
        },
        ticks: {
          display: false
        }   
      }],
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="90"></canvas>
```

Comment: Is is possible to have a way that the image can use colored svg icons in the img.src

e.g. using 
<svg focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="#34a853" d="M10 2v2a6 6 0 0 1 6 6h2a8 8 0 0 0-8-8"></path><path fill="#ea4335" d="M10 4V2a8 8 0 0 0-8 8h2c0-3.3 2.7-6 6-6"></path><path fill="#fbbc04" d="M4 10H2a8 8 0 0 0 8 8v-2c-3.3 0-6-2.69-6-6"></path><path fill="#4285f4" d="M22 20.59l-5.69-5.69A7.96 7.96 0 0 0 18 10h-2a6 6 0 0 1-6 6v2c1.85 0 3.52-.64 4.88-1.68l5.69 5.69L22 20.59"></path></svg>

as the image icon for the tick lables?