# how to modify horizontal bar chart using chart js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, bar-chart, chart.js2

Please see the line I have highlighted.

1. How to add labels on Y-axis
2. How to make 0 position verticle line as a dotted line.
3. How to make rounded corner as mention in the photo.

I need to modify the chart js bar graph.

[image]

But it's very complicated to modify it. If someone has an idea about chart js your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figuring this out requires looking through chart.js configurations [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/).

1. To add a label on another line for the Y-axis your labels need the following structure `labels: [["Dept1", 81], ["Dept2", 82], ["Dept3", 83]]`.
2. Chart.js 2.0 can handle negative values by default so all you need to do is pass in your respective data points. Something like this should be fine: `data: [12, -19, 5],`
3. The rounded corners problem is a little trickier. I used an external library linked [here](https://github.com/jedtrow/Chart.js-Rounded-Bar-Charts). There is some canvas rendering trickery going on. Be sure to star his repo to give the author credit!

Resulting Fiddle here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gKRQZG?editors=1000

Comment: Can we add image in labels..?

Comment: I thought about this problem when trying to add icons to labels. It turns out chart.js doesn't support it. There may be a way to do it, but it's not a simple task.

Comment: Did you get any idea about the image to add on yaxis.

Comment: I would look into: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36979474/how-to-change-the-labels-to-the-image-icon-in-bar-chart-js?rq=1 and https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/1554

Comment: Hi Joseph,I can achieve the dotted line now. If you have idea on how to reduce the size of y-axis label while resizing the window.
**'Department 1'**
**'-10'** which come in two row.

Comment: You could try editing the canvas, but you would need to edit chart.js source code. Unfortunately there is no simple way to do it in chart.js API https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html

Comment: Thanks for your time. Yes, by modifying the chart we can achieve that. I have resolved it.